# What is the correct Windows Update configuration within the OS when using Azure Update Management

Tags: azure, windows-update

We have started using Azure Update Management for our Windows VM's in Azure.

But I cannot find any documentation, indicating the recommended Windows Update configuration settings in the OS.

For example, should we use Sconfig within the OS and set Windows Updates to Manual, or Disabled, or some other custom setting?

Does anyone know of any documentation I may have missed or have any recommendations on this?

Answer (score 1):

Update Management relies on Windows Update to download and install Windows Updates. As a result, we respect many of the settings used by Windows Update. If you use settings to enable non-Windows updates, Update Management will manage those updates as well. If you want to enable downloading updates before an update deployment occurs, update deployments can go faster and be less likely to exceed the maintenance window.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management#firstparty-predownload

Customers who have invested in System Center Configuration Manager to manage PCs, servers, and mobile devices also rely on its strength and maturity in managing software updates as part of their software update management (SUM) cycle.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/oms-solution-updatemgmt-sccmintegration

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a few hours trying to answer the same question after my Azure VMs recently began install updates and restarting themselves outside of the Deployment Schedule configured in Azure Update Management.

Found this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/configure-wuagent

[It recommends a specific setting for Automatic Updates of 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/configure-wuagent#pre-download-updates), which will configure OS Windows Updates to pre-download updates, but not install them.

[It them goes on to recommend you consider Reboot settings for your environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/configure-wuagent#configure-reboot-settings) while this offers absolutely no guidance on how to configure for use with Azure Update Management, based on my configuration and testing this is irrelevant as long as you have Automatic Updates set to 3 as per above (as nothing should ever be installed by the OS, therefore the settings should never apply).

Hope this helps anyone else that might come acorss this issue as well!